# Dynamically replace, filter column value in python

Tags: python, loops

Is there a method to replace the column name that is filtering the values in a dataframe?
For eg:

```
new_df = old_df[old_df['Employee_Name'] == 'Dynamic_value')].reset_index().replace("Dynamic_value",i)
```

i = this is an iterator that takes value from a list and in each iteration that value changes.

Answer (score 0):

If `Dynamic_value` is only present in the `Employee_Name` columns (or if you don't want to consider other columns), then the values to take from the iterator are the number of rows in `new_df`:

```
new_df = old_df[(old_df['Employee_Name'] == 'Dynamic_value')].reset_index()
new_df['Employee_Name'] = [next(i) for _ in range(len(new_df))]
```

Example output:

```
   index Employee_Name      Other_col
0      2             a              F
1      4             b  Dynamic_value
```

If you can have many columns, then use a mask:

```
new_df = old_df[(old_df['Employee_Name'] == 'Dynamic_value')].reset_index()
m = new_df.eq('Dynamic_value')
new_df[m] = [next(i) for _ in range(m.to_numpy().sum())]
```

Example output:

```
   index Employee_Name Other_col
0      2             a         F
1      4             b         c
```

Used input:

```
old_df = pd.DataFrame({'Employee_Name': ['A', 'B', 'Dynamic_value', 'D', 'Dynamic_value'],
                       'Other_col': ['E', 'Dynamic_value', 'F', 'G', 'Dynamic_value']
                      })
i = iter(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])


   Employee_Name      Other_col
0              A              E
1              B  Dynamic_value
2  Dynamic_value              F
3              D              G
4  Dynamic_value  Dynamic_value
```

Comment: No this is not what I am expecting i is iterating a list of names . For eg : lets assume a list has names ['Name1','Name2','Name3']. if i put the filtering function mentioned above inside a for loop, then during first iteration 'Dynamic Value' must be replaced with 'Name1' and data will be ssaved in another dataframe and second iteration will be replaced wuth Name2 and so on

Comment: @PHegde can you then provide a minimal example (input, `i` and expected output?). I used an iterator that generates numbers here but it would work with any iterator.